# How to tell python I want to invoke lists in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I wanna use recursion to merge two sorted lists. In the function, I use if sentence to deal with 3
situations: 1.P and Q are not None 2.P is None 3.Q is None.

But computer take P and Q as 'int' type.
It's the bug tip:
`'int' object is not suscriptable`

```
P=[1,2,3,5,6,7]
Q=[2,5,6,8,9]
R=[]
i=j=0
lp=len(P)
lq=len(Q)
def merge(P,Q,R):
    if P and Q:
        if P[0]>Q[0]:
            R.append(Q[0])
            merge(P,Q[1:],R)
        elif P[0]<Q[0]:
            R.append(P[0])
            merge(P[1:],Q[0],R)
        else:
            R.append(P[0])
            R.append(Q[0])
    elif P:
        R.extend(P)
    else:
        R.extend(Q)
merge(P,Q,R)
print(R)
```

Comment: `merge(P[1:],Q[0],R)` here `Q[0]` is an int. Typo?

Comment: That's because in the second recursive call, you're passing `Q[0]`, which is an int. Probably you wanted to pass `Q` directly.

Comment: Thanks. After change Q[0] to Q. Computer doesn't suggest syntax error anymore. Besides, I just found there should be "merge(P[1:],Q[1:],R)" when P[0]==Q[0]. This code could run now!